# DataTextField from field's property

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatextfield

I have class something like

```
public class A
{
    public string name;
}

public class B
{
    public int Id;
    public A obj;
}
```

Then, I have ASP.NET WebForms application and page with ListBox control.

I want to set `List<B>` as DataSource of `ListBox`.

```
List<B> list = ...; //fill data
lbx.DataSource = list;
lbx.DataValueField = "Id";
lbx.DataTextField = A.name; //how can I do it?
lbx.DataBind();
```

So, my question is: how can I link DataTextField to property of object in list?

Thank you!

Comment: `DataTextField` takes a string.

Comment: yes, I khow. But is there way to solve my problem?

Comment: If it is possible, Try B inherits from A (B : A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a property in the B class for the Name. For Example

```
public class B
{
public int Id;
public A obj;
public string Name{ get {return obj.name;}}
}
```

use it as 
     `lbx.DataTextField = "Name";`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether the listbox control you are using supports Nested properties ( I knew some third party control does it), something like this:

```
lbx.DataTextField = "obj.name"
```

If it does not support, then wrap the nested property of A into another readonly property of B:

```
public class B
{
    public int Id;
    public A obj;
    public string NameOfA
    {
       Get{return obj.name;}
    }
}
```

then:

```
lbx.DataTextField = "NameOfA"
```